# What is best way to validate angular template markup

Tags: angular, lint

In our angular 5 project we've seen several instances of developers committing html markup in templates with missing closing tags / quotations, etc. Is there a tool to check the templates similar to what lint does for js files?

Comment: It's pretty standard to ensure proper tabbing to eliminate the chances for missing a closing tag. Also, a missing closing tag should be quickly spotted during dev since this will cause your app to crash. Seems like a tool to check this is almost useless, and probably costs more time than saves. Code formatting is a requirement for any well developed application.

Comment: good point. thanks